# No recibo una variable post enviada mediante ajax a php

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, post

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con php, ajax, jquery y html.

Tengo un formulario donde guardo imágenes que se ingresan en un input file, las envio por medio de ajax y las guardo en carpetas con php, el nombre de la carpeta viene de un input que se llena de acuerdo a

```
              <form method="post" id="frmGuardarServicio" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <input type="hidden" id="idSolGuardarServicio" name="idSolGuardarServicio">

                <div class="panel panel-default">

                  <div class="panel-heading">Fotos antes</div>

                  <div class="panel-body">

                    <label>Seleccione las imagenes</label>

                    <input type="file" name="imagenesAntes[]" id="inputImagenesAntes" multiple class="form-control">                  

                  </div>

                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="cancelarFotos">Cancelar</button>

                <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" id="btnTerminarServicio">Guardar</button>

              </form>
```

El input "idSolGuardarServicio", le asigno un valor por medio de jquery.

```
        $("#idSolGuardarServicio").val($(".idSolTerminar").html());

        $.ajax({

            url : "ajax/subirImagenes.php",
            method : "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(respuesta){
        })
```

Luego con php guardo las imagenes en una carpeta que se crea con el codigo que viene en el input "idSolGuardarServicio".

```
if(is_array($_FILES)){  

  $rutaAntes = "../vistas/img/evidencias/antes/".$_POST["idSolGuardarServicio"];

  mkdir($rutaAntes,0777, true);

  foreach($_FILES['imagenesAntes']['name'] as $name => $value){

    $file_name = explode(".", $_FILES['imagenesAntes']['name'][$name]);
    $allowed_extension = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");

    if(in_array($file_name[1], $allowed_extension)){

      $new_name = rand(1, 100) . '.'. $file_name[1];

      $sourcePath = $_FILES["imagenesAntes"]["tmp_name"][$name];

      $targetPath = $rutaAntes."/".$new_name;

      move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath);

    }

  }
}
```

El código funciona desde el pc, pero cuando lo intento en un dispositivo móvil, me muestra un error que dice: "undefined index idSolGuardarServicio", realmente no se cual sea el error, o si tal vez esto se tenga que hacer diferente para cuando es un dispositivo móvil.

Les agradezco la ayuda para solucionar este error.

Comment: `.idSolTerminar` de dónde lo sacas?

Comment: Es una etiqueta que almacena el código que el usuario esta trabajando, al iniciar el programa el usuario da clic en un botón que coloca el código en esa etiqueta.

Comment: Coloca también el html donde está esa etiqueta

Comment: <h3 class="box-title">Datos servicio Id Sol # <span class="idSolTerminar"></span></h3>

Comment: No tiene nada que ver que se haga desde un móvil o no, porque ese código correría en el servidor, no en el móvil. Lo único que podría ocasionar eso es que desde el móvil no llenes los datos correctamente o que el móvil tenga bloqueado Javascript o algo así.